# Retrieve properties of child node

Tags: java, aem, jcr

I'm pretty new to java so bear with me. I'm trying to retrieve the properties of a child node. For instance I'm trying to retrieve all the properties associated with the image property:

```
/content
    /foo
        /jcr:content 
            /page
               /page_child
                  /image <-----
```

Currently my script is retrieving all the properties from page_child but how do I get the properties of "image"

```
public void setPageContext(PageContext context) {
    ValueMap properties = (ValueMap) context.getAttribute("properties");
    closeText = properties.get("closeText", "");
    imageURL = properties.get("fileReference", "");
}

public String getCloseText() { return closeText; }
public String getCloseText() { return imageURL; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at /libs/foundation/components/adaptiveimage

In the JSP, they are creating a new Resource using the jcr:content of the image file.

```
Resource fileJcrContent = resource.getChild("file").getChild("jcr:content");
if (fileJcrContent != null) {
    ValueMap fileProperties = fileJcrContent.adaptTo(ValueMap.class);
    String mimeType = fileProperties.get("jcr:mimeType", "jpg");
    extension = mimeType.substring(mimeType.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
}
```

From there, all properties will be accessible through fileProperties.